# Command to open all files with a specified extension the current folder using Unix Terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, alias

I want to create an alias that opens all files with extension .xcworkspace in the current directory through terminal.

What's the command to open all files with the specified extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cd to the directory, and enter:

```
open *.xcworkspace
```

To create an alias,

```
alias openstuff="open *.xcworkspace"
```

Comment: the command works on its own, but the alias doesn't:
The file /Users/user/Desktop/x/xProject/*.xcworkspace does not exist.

Comment: Hmm... I've tried it on `zsh` and `bash`.  What shell are you using?  `echo $SHELL` will tell you, if you're unsure.